# How to create a Trigger in oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, triggers

I have oracle database 11gR2 and i want to create some triggers automatically with a block .
when i want to run query in below , i have an error .

My block is :

```
declare
  tablesid number ;
  tablenames varchar2(4000);
  cursor c1 is
  select id , title from hr.tables;

begin
    open c1;
    loop
      fetch c1 into tablesid , tablenames;
     CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER tablenames||'_before_insert'
      before insert
      on hr.tablenames
      DECLARE

     columnid number ;
      columnval number ;
      columntitle varchar(4000);

      cursor c2 is
      select id from hr.columns where tableid = tablesid ;   
      BEGIN

      -- open c2 ;
       for rec in c2 loop
       select title into columntitle from hr.columns where id = rec.id
       insert into hr.rowaction(columnid,newvalue,oldvalue,actiondate)
       (
         select  id ,:new.columntitle,:old.columntitle,sysdate  
         from hr.tabletiltes
         where id = rec.id
      )
      select title into columntitle from hr.columns where id = rec.id;
      dbms_output.put_line(columntitle);
     end loop;
    end;
    end loop ;close c1; end;
```

> ORA-06550: line 11, column 6:
>   PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "CREATE" when expecting one of the following:
>      ( begin case declare end exit for goto if loop mod null
>      pragma raise return select update while with 
>        <<
>      continue close current delete fetch lock insert open rollback
>      savepoint set sql execute commit forall merge pipe purge
>   06550. 00000 -  "line %s, column %s:\n%s"
>   *Cause:    Usually a PL/SQL compilation error.
>   *Action :
>   Bind Variable "new" is NOT DECLARED
>   anonymous block completed
>   Bind Variable "new" is NOT DECLARED
>   anonymous block completed

Thanks

Comment: From the comment, saeed.sh asked a procedure to build triggers that will save data when it changes, for every table of the database. This is big solution asked.

Answer (score 4):

A trigger is a standalone separate piece of code that is usually considered `DDL`, the language that defines metadata for objects.

You cannot have a trigger declaration embedded inside a PL/SQL block.  IF you need to CREATE some PL/SQL code on the fly - not a great idea - consider the `DMBS_DDL.CREATE_WRAPPED` procedure.  You seem to have `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE` in mind as well.  If so, have a read on this: (http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14258/d_ddl.htm)

You should define your trigger BEFORE running your PL/SQL in other words.  Make two scripts.

Comment: i want to save all changes in database . i have 3 tables : tables , columns ,rowaction . in tables , saving name of all tables , in columns , saving name of all columns with tableid . i want to save old value and new value before and after insert in tables in rowaction . so i should to create triggers for all tables in database automatically with procedure. i have an idea i explain it in question , do you have any ?

Comment: This is a whole project! We did it here for our parameterization tables, and it is a brilliant piece of code. But I won't give it since I did not make it myself.

Comment: Just my experience, and I wasn't doing a trigger in a loop, but when I programmatically created one similar to this (not using a wrapper), I had to run the `CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER x` through to the `END;` line, then run `ALTER TRIGGER x ENABLE;` in a separate command to apply a trigger programmatically, and still got this "Enter Binds" window in between to click on (which is maybe why you can't go straight to the next command?).  Did not have to use `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE` and got an error when I tried it that way.

Comment: Yes, in order to run any DDL statement (including but not limited to `CREATE TRIGGER`) in plsql block you must use `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE`